# Why are ends of a standing wave not counted as nodes?

Tags: waves, acoustics

In a youtube video i came across a very elegant experiment of standing waves.A comment on the video sparked my curiosity.

I put up the link in here.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QcoQvzNQp6Q
(explanation)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-gr7KmTOrx0
(demonstration)

In this videos i found a comment.

Wrong the things with the nodes (a common mistake, indeed)

It is true that there is nodes at the ends of the string. But those do not count. They are part of the (Dirichlet) boundary conditions, not part of the dynamics. So they must not be counted. That is why "the ground state has NO nodes"﻿

Why does dirichlet function come here?
Why is this done so?

Comment: It says Dirichlet Boundary Conditions, not Dirichlet functions. The former applies to ordinary differential equations, the latter to partial differentiation equations.